# Get week start timestamp and week end timestamp using Java SE API and Joda Time (based on ISO)

Tags: java, time, iso

How may I get week start timestamp (2010-03-01 00:00:00 UTC) and week end timestamp (2010-03-08 00:00:00 UTC) given a java.util.Date (or Joda DateTime), or year and ISO week number, using Java SE API and Joda Time?

Answer (score 1):

JodaTime has support for ISO week numbers (see [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html#weekOfWeekyear)). For example:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
int isoWeek = dateTime.getWeekOfWeekyear();
```

You can also set the "start of  aweek" using something like this:

```
DateTime startOfWeek = dateTime.withWeekOfWeekyear(4).withDayOfWeek(1).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
```